# Map and files c++

Tags: c++, file

I want mymap to have capacity for 3 elements, if I keep inserting elements that will erase the last one entered for example..
Insert element and write into the file

`typename map <string, pair<T,int> > ::iterator i = mymap.find(key);`

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
```

this works, but when i delete an element from mymap its deleted from file too.

```
i = mymap.find(last.first);
mymap.erase(i);
```

Why?

Comment: Do you know that you save a pointer to an intertor in the file, and no data?

Comment: I'm not sure what type `i` is, but generally a `reinterpret_cast` to, well, any type is probably a bad idea. Consider writing a proper serialization function, not relying on binary compatibility of the data. With `const char*`, you *might* not be hitting UB with appropriate assumptions (assuming your type is POD and trivial, for instance), but you're definitely living life on the edge.

Answer (score 1):

The data managed by a `std::map<>` object is not embedded directly in the `std::map<>` object - instead, it's dynamically allocated and the `std::map<>` object contains pointers to parts of the data so it can start a search.  When you `file.write` you're only writing out the management object and not the nodes - that will never persist the data.  After:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<T, int>> mymap;
mymap.emplace("one", {1.0, 1});
mymap.emplace("two", {2.0, 2});
```

You might imagine the memory areas in use and the pointers between them like this:

```
mymap:{size=2; p_root_=&MMM; p_least_=&AAA; p_greatest_=&ZZZ;}
                          |             /                /
...on the heap...      +--|-------------        ---------
                       |  v                    /
                       |  MMM                 /
                       v /   \               /
                       ZZZ   AAA<-----------/
```

If you want to have a container that remembers the last 3 values, consider using a circular buffer (or if you're not overly concerned about performance - even easier, a `std::deque<>`), though you'll then have to store the keys and values and manually search over the 3 values to find a match on a key.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much for the explanation!